# Oracle service isn't started on Ubuntu load

Tags: startup, services, oracle

I've installed Oracle 11g on Ubuntu 10.10

I could access `https://localhost:1158/em` web-interface OK.

After reboot, I don't think the Oracle service was started, because I can't access this link more.

Is there a way to start it manually just in one command, without having to write an additional script?

Thank you.

**[EDIT]**

`lsnrctl start` command gives:
 `TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started` so it's looks ok

if execute `dbstart` nothing happens

sudo -u oracle dbstart gives:
 command not found

command line:

```
oracle@edbwp400352:/etc/init.d$ sudo sh oracledb start
[sudo] password for oracle: 
Starting Oracle: 
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 24-MAR-2011 20:28:34

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started
OK
```

command:`oracle@edbwp400352:/etc/init.d$ emctl start oms`
gives:

```
ulimit: 25: bad number
Environment variable ORACLE_UNQNAME not defined. Please set ORACLE_UNQNAME to database unique name.
```

Comment: That used to work -- I don't know if the method has changed.  Do you have anything in /etc/init.d/ related to oracle or db* ?

Comment: ohh, actually i tried from this resource http://www.pythian.com/news/654/installing-oracle-11g-on-ubuntu-linux-710-gutsy-gibbon/

Comment: it connected with /etc/init.d/oracledb script

Comment: I've added command line output to post.It looks all is OK,but localhost em is still unavailable

Comment: Nice.   It looks like the command I was looking for was the equivalent of `su $ORACLE_OWNR -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart"`

Comment: If you run `netstat -aunt | grep :1158` do you see a listening process?

Comment: have run, no listening process

Comment: should I start em by some specific command?

Comment: i've edited post,tried to do:emctl start oms

Comment: You might want to see this as well : http://www.pythian.com/news/13291/installing-oracle-11gr2-enterprise-edition-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen how to do it in one command.  This one-liner might work:

`sudo -u oracle lsnrctl start && sudo -u oracle dbstart`

Comment: for <code>lsnrctl start</code> command: TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started
so it's look OK

Comment: if execute dbstart nothing happens

Comment: could you see [EDIT],please

Comment: yes,just nothig out in console,and still can't access https://localhost:1158/em

Answer (score 0):

Start the Oracle XE 11gR2 server using the command:

```
  sudo service oracle-xe start
```

Comment: *Already used. Passion for programming